# Use EBean with ElasticSearch only in Play

Tags: java, elasticsearch, playframework, ebean

I am using Java for Play and I am trying to make EBean work only with elasticsearch. I do not need or want a database connection, as I do not plan to store my data in a database, only in elasticsearch.

Here is my application.conf

```
ebean.docstoreonly=true
ebean.docstore.url="http://dockermachine:9200"
ebean.docstore.active=true
ebean.docstore.generateMapping=true
ebean.docstore.dropCreate=true
```

Unfortunately, when I ran the project I get the following error:

```
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: conf\application.conf: 33: docstoreonly has type BOOLEAN rather than LIST
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:163)
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:174)
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:188)
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:193)
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getList(SimpleConfig.java:262)
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getHomogeneousUnwrappedList(SimpleConfig.java:348)
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getStringList(SimpleConfig.java:406)
[error]     at play.db.ebean.EbeanParsedConfig.lambda$parseFromConfig$5(EbeanParsedConfig.java:72)
[error]     at java.util.Map.forEach(Map.java:630)
[error]     at play.db.ebean.EbeanParsedConfig.parseFromConfig(EbeanParsedConfig.java:66)
[error]     at play.db.ebean.EbeanParsedConfig.parseFromConfig(EbeanParsedConfig.java:47)
[error]     at play.db.ebean.ModelsConfigLoader.apply(ModelsConfigLoader.java:28)
[error]     at play.db.ebean.ModelsConfigLoader.apply(ModelsConfigLoader.java:21)
[error]     at play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean$.$anonfun$configuredEbeanModels$4(PlayEbean.scala:153)
[error]     at play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean$.withClassLoader$1(PlayEbean.scala:130)
[error]     at play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean$.$anonfun$configuredEbeanModels$1(PlayEbean.scala:150)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:39)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:66)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:262)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:271)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:262)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:174)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:36)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: conf\application.conf: 33: docstoreonly has type BOOLEAN rather than LIST
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:163)
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:174)
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:188)
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:193)
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getList(SimpleConfig.java:262)
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getHomogeneousUnwrappedList(SimpleConfig.java:348)
[error]     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getStringList(SimpleConfig.java:406)
[error]     at play.db.ebean.EbeanParsedConfig.lambda$parseFromConfig$5(EbeanParsedConfig.java:72)
[error]     at java.util.Map.forEach(Map.java:630)
[error]     at play.db.ebean.EbeanParsedConfig.parseFromConfig(EbeanParsedConfig.java:66)
[error]     at play.db.ebean.EbeanParsedConfig.parseFromConfig(EbeanParsedConfig.java:47)
[error]     at play.db.ebean.ModelsConfigLoader.apply(ModelsConfigLoader.java:28)
[error]     at play.db.ebean.ModelsConfigLoader.apply(ModelsConfigLoader.java:21)
[error]     at play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean$.$anonfun$configuredEbeanModels$4(PlayEbean.scala:153)
[error]     at play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean$.withClassLoader$1(PlayEbean.scala:130)
[error]     at play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean$.$anonfun$configuredEbeanModels$1(PlayEbean.scala:150)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:39)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:66)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:262)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:271)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:262)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:174)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:36)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (module1 / Compile / playEbeanModels) com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: conf\application.conf: 33: docstoreonly has type BOOLEAN rather than LIST
[error] (module2 / Compile / playEbeanModels) com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: conf\application.conf: 33: docstoreonly has type BOOLEAN rather than LIST
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Apr 23, 2018 5:06:00 PM
```

I was following example found on github: https://github.com/ebean-orm-examples/example-elasticsearch-only
It says that `ebean.docstoreonly` should be set to true, but it seems that it requires List.
I am using `sbt-play-ebean` plugin

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.1.0")
```

which internally uses EBean version 11.7.x

My build.sbt has dependency to this ebean-elastic component:

```
 "io.ebean" % "ebean-elastic" % "11.15.1"
```

Is using, elasticsearch only, in EBean possible, or should I use some other method, like elasticsearch official java sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long trial and error, here is the solution:

It seems that `application.conf` is not the place where I should store ebean properties. It is supposed to be a separate file, located in the same directory where `application.conf` resides.

File should be named `ebean.properties`:

```
ebean.elasticsearch.docStoreOnly=true
ebean.elasticsearch.docstore.url=http://dockermachine:9200
ebean.elasticsearch.docstore.active=true
ebean.elasticsearch.docstore.generateMapping=true
ebean.elasticsearch.docstore.dropCreate=true
ebean.elasticsearch.docstore.pathToResources=conf
```

There are a couple things to note here:

1. As I understood `ebean.properties` is necessary here, because `application.conf` cannot interpret key/value pairs that is unknown to it and will default to LIST. This should be the job of `sbt-play-ebean` plugin for play, but it seems that plugin is outdated (someone might give me better explanation)
2. `ebean.docstoreonly` is wrong. This is the correct casing of it: `ebean.docStoreOnly`.
3. Generated mapping json files will not be created if you do not have proper folders created. By default, ebean generates mapping files to `src/main/resources`. This will work in Maven builds, but with sbt build tool and play framework that needs to go inside `/conf` folder of the project (or the sub-module). That is why I needed to override `ebean.elasticsearch.docstore.pathToResources`
4. H2 dependency was needed as well in sbt (if you do not have already): `"com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.196"`. Not sure why (as I am not having any backing database), but I was getting ClassNotFoundExceptions.
5. Project that I work on is specific that I need some data only on elasticsearch, and some data only on the actual database. Ebean-elastic is designed to be an backing index of the models stored in database. If you enable 
   `docStoreOnly` then ebean will no longer do any writes inside the actual database. To make it work, then you need to create two ebean servers: one that connects to the database only, and one that is communicating with elasticsearch only. In my case, default ebeanserver was used for database only connections (no changes were done there) and I was accessing it by default: `EbeanServer db = Ebean.getDefaultServer();`. For elasticsearch only I had to configure separate ebeanserver. That is why in `ebean.properties` I have `elasticsearch` (name of the ebean server) between `ebean` and other configuration settings. So basically, `ebean.properties` defines new ebean server named `elasticsearch`. There are no other configuration requirements besides this. Inside code, I am using elasticsearch only ebean server like this: `EbeanServer dbes = Ebean.getServer("elasticsearch");`